# Exception in session-scoped pytest fixture is reported for every test that uses that fixture -- I only want to see it once

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I have a heavily-used fixture that sometimes errors out and makes it impossible to run the tests that use it (this is due to hardware errors, so it's not fixable). When it fails, pytest prints the same error for every single test that uses that fixture, meaning that suddenly I get thousands of lines out of output with the real error message at the top, and other errors hidden in the flood. I am looking for some option so that I only get the error once instead of hundreds of times.

A quick example:

My test file:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def buggy_fixture():
    print("Making buggy fixture")
    raise RuntimeError("Oh no, a bug")

def test_1(buggy_fixture):
    print("test 1")

def test_2(buggy_fixture):
    print("test 2")
```

The output:

```
% pytest test_stuff.py
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.5.2, pytest-3.9.3, py-1.7.0, pluggy-0.8.0
benchmark: 3.2.2 (defaults: timer=time.perf_counter disable_gc=False min_rounds=5 min_time=0.000005 max_time=1.0 calibration_precision=10 warmup=False warmup_iterations=100000)
rootdir: /home/test/a, inifile:
plugins: timeout-1.3.3, benchmark-3.2.2, repeat-0.8.0
collected 2 items                                                              

test_stuff.py EE                                                         [100%]

==================================== ERRORS ====================================
___________________________ ERROR at setup of test_1 ___________________________

    @pytest.fixture(scope='session')
    def buggy_fixture():
        print("Making buggy fixture")
>       raise RuntimeError("Oh no, a bug")
E       RuntimeError: Oh no, a bug

test_stuff.py:6: RuntimeError
---------------------------- Captured stdout setup -----------------------------
Making buggy fixture
___________________________ ERROR at setup of test_2 ___________________________

    @pytest.fixture(scope='session')
    def buggy_fixture():
        print("Making buggy fixture")
>       raise RuntimeError("Oh no, a bug")
E       RuntimeError: Oh no, a bug

test_stuff.py:6: RuntimeError
=========================== 2 error in 0.04 seconds ============================
```

This is something closer to what I would like to see:

```
% pytest test_stuff.py   
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.5.2, pytest-3.9.3, py-1.7.0, pluggy-0.8.0
benchmark: 3.2.2 (defaults: timer=time.perf_counter disable_gc=False min_rounds=5 min_time=0.000005 max_time=1.0 calibration_precision=10 warmup=False warmup_iterations=100000)
rootdir: /home/test/a, inifile:
plugins: timeout-1.3.3, benchmark-3.2.2, repeat-0.8.0
collected 2 items                                                              

test_stuff.py EE                                                         [100%]

==================================== ERRORS ====================================
_________________________ ERROR at setup of buggy_fixture ______________________

    @pytest.fixture(scope='session')
    def buggy_fixture():
        print("Making buggy fixture")
>       raise RuntimeError("Oh no, a bug")
E       RuntimeError: Oh no, a bug

test_stuff.py:6: RuntimeError
---------------------------- Captured stdout setup -----------------------------
Making buggy fixture
=========================== 2 error in 0.04 seconds ============================
```

Notes:

- `pytest.exit` is a possible solution, but I would still like to run tests using other fixtures
- Calling `pytest.skip` on an error in the fixture causes the exception to never get printed -- I still want to see it the first time
- In our real tests, every test uses the same fixture, but it is paramaterized. This parameter ends up as part of the test name, so it's clear that if the fixture fails, those tests won't get run.

Edited because the problem is with a scoped fixture: in the original example, I showed a fixture that ran for every test, and there it makes sense to print the error multiple times. Now it shows that the error only happens once but is printed multiple times.

Comment: A session fixture has to execute once to be cached. Since an error is raised, the result is not cached, so the next test tries to evaluate the fixture again. You can catch the error in the fixture, output it to terminal and skip the affected tests.

Comment: @hoefling I'm pretty sure the fixture is not getting re-evaluated. If I add a file write to it, the file only gets written once. I'm not sure how to write to the terminal, since the output is thrown away unless the test fails, but if I fail the first test then we're back to the original issue that it will show the message for all the tests.

Comment: Yes, looks like I'm wrong, the exception is stored as evaluation result and reraised on each result access. To turn off output capture inside the fixture and print to terminal, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57218543/2650249).

Comment: Thank you for the link. Your idea prints approximately what I want, but it unfortunately does not integrate well with other tooling. Pytest returns successfully because all the tests were skipped, and I don't think the result would appear in the xml report generated by --junit-xml. If I could get the first test to fail and the rest to be skipped, that would be ideal.